# Python go to specific iteration in generator

Tags: python, generator

I'm looking for a way to navigate to a particular iteration in a generator object.

I have a generator object that goes through a list of JSON objects. Instead of loading all of them at once, I created a generator so that each JSON object loads only at each iteration.

```
def read_data(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as data_file:
        for user in data_file:
            yield json.loads(user)
```

However, now I am looking for some way to navigate to the nth iteration to retrieve more data on that user. The only way I can think of doing this is iterating through the generator and stopping on the nth enumeration:

```
n = 3
data = read_data(file_name)
for num, user in enumerate(data):
    if num == n:
        <retrieve more data>
```

Any better ways to do this?

Comment: That's fundamentally how you have to do it, but you should probably use `itertools.islice()`. Can't do a full answer; I'm on my phone :P.

Comment: You could / should store the results in a `list` if you're going back and forth in the results.

Comment: There you go, I answered anyway :P.

Comment: @Cyphase is there a way to create a dictionary? maybe of objects that point to the iteration?

Comment: You could create an object with a 'dict'-like interface, but you can't reverse an iterator; you'd have to store the past values. There might be a better way to do what you want though. Just let me get to my computer :).

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? How much data are you working with?

Comment: @Cyphase oh dang, ya storing is not an option. I'm currently not using a lot of data but my work should be able to scale to larger data sets (millions of users)

Comment: How many millions? How large is each user object?

Comment: I'm only asking to make sure that you do actually need more sophisticated methods :).

Comment: I'm gonna start working on something to do what I think you want; sounds like fun :).

Comment: Just to mention though, depending on your exact usage, you might be able to use a database to do this pretty easily.

Comment: @Cyphase Aww, a database might be what I'm missing here! map each user with a key and then call the database key!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
from itertools import islice

def nth(iterable, n, default=None):
    "Returns the nth item or a default value"
    return next(islice(iterable, n, None), default)
```

This is one of many [useful utilities included in the `itertools` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

Comment: Thanks for fixing the indentation Anand; I'm on my phone and I accidentally posted without properly formatting it :P.

Comment: Thanks Padraic. Using my phone is no excuse for sloppy answers :).

Comment: works nicely. i'll consider mapping each user to a database key if performance doesn't meet my requirements. thanks for the help!